# Non-causal LTI system - specific case

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dynamical-systems, z-transform

I am given the following signals :

**input signal**

$x_{[n]} = (\frac{1}{2})^nu_{[n]} + 2^nu_{[-n-1]}$

The signal apparetnly starts in $ n=-\infty$ and goes to $n=\infty$.

**system output**

$y_{[n]} = 6(\frac{1}{2})^nu_{[n]} - 6(\frac{3}{4})^nu_{[n]}$

The response starts at $n=0$.

The question is to state the impulse response $h_{[n]}$ of such system.

**my question**

How to understand a system that "tolerates" infinite input from $n=-\infty$ to $n=-1$ and only then, at $n=0$ starts to respond ? For me this seems somehow flawed.

**analysis**

I have tried to calculate z-transform, to obtain $H_{(z)}$, I believe I can get rid of the same roots and zeros and thus arriving at :

$H_{(z)} = \frac{Y_{(z)}}{X_{(z)}} = \frac{1-2z^{-1}}{1-(\frac{3}{4})z^{-1}}$

Which still somehow doesnt provide me with much choice for inverse z-transform.

Comment: You should not chancel unstable poles and zeros. Did you check if the poles and zeros were stable?

Comment: good question :



z - transform is as follows :

$Y_{(z)} = 6\frac{1}{1-(\frac{1}{2})z^{-1}} - 6\frac{1}{1-(\frac{3}{4})z^{-1}}$

$X_{(z)} = \frac{1}{1-(\frac{1}{2})z^{-1}} - \frac{1}{1-2z^{-1}}$


so the only things I can then cancel out are $z$ and $(z-\frac{1}{2})$, both of which are inside unit circle.



Please correct me if I am somewhere wrong.

Comment: I was not implying that you had an error, I just wanted to make sure if you did consider this point.